# redis-server service:cannot open PID file var/ru

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, redis

I am new to Ubuntu server. I have installed redis on Ubuntu 18.04 server, then I run this command if re`enter dis is active

`sudo systemctl status redis`

then it says:

`redis-server service:cannot open PID file var/ru sysytemd[1]:started Advanced key value line 1-15`

Now my console is not taking any normal command, it just says log file:...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPlkD.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has configured systemctl to send output through the `less` pager. You can just press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit and return to your terminal session.

You can prevent this behavior by using the `--no-pager` command line option, or permanently by setting the `SYSTEMD_PAGER` environment variable to the empty string. For example, you might place this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
export SYSTEMD_PAGER=''
```

---

You are not having a problem with redis and can ignore the message about a missing PID file.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 20.04  the /etc/redis/redis.conf file find

```
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
```

and change to

```
pidfile /run/redis/redis-server.pid
```

the systemctl on ubuntu 20.04 checks for `"/run/redis/redis-server.pid"` file and cant find it. As a result the systemctl restarts services